# Linux command to print a tree like directory structure

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm trying to write a script which will print directories, subdirectories and their files in a tree structure, but without using tree command.

Example:

```
DIR: A 
     f1
     f2 
     DIR: B
          f3 
DIR: C
     file1
     file21
```

I have tried multiple of solutions, but I always ran into the problem that I could not distinguish between a directory or a file, therefore I could not apply the right formatting. The "DIR: " prefix makes it complicated. Is there something very obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

You may try variant of these command also

`find . -type d -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'`

`find . -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'`

`find .  | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'`

`find -type d`

`tree -l`

Answer (score 2):

Use the the `-d` test:

```
if [ -d "$path" ] ; then
    echo DIR
fi
```

Comment: Or generally: the first bit of the permissions is the file type, and if it's `d` it's a directory.